# HTML5 Audio: preload attribute ignored in Chrome

Tags: html, audio, google-chrome, html5-audio

My code is basically this

```
<audio controls preload="none" src="linktofile.mp3" />
```

It works great in Safari 5 and Chrome 8 except that Chrome completely ignores the preload attribute and starts loading (not playing) the file after page load. Which consumes a huge amount of bandwidth if the page is full of audio tags.

Is there a way to make Chrome behave like Safari 5 (ie. the right way) and only load a file when the user clicks on the play button ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Chrome [bug #16482](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16482) , and still not fixed, nope.

Update: As of April 6, 2011 it is fixed :-)

Comment: In that issue they are talking about latency... Is it the same problem ? Thanks. It's really annoying to see that they didn't fix it even though they're aware of it since July 09.

Comment: Yes its the same issue, it ignores `preload` attribute.

Comment: As of 6 April 2011, [vkr comments on the bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16482#c72): `The patches to implement preload have now landed! The preload attribute will be finally recognized in Chrome 12. (Dev channel should get this update in a few weeks.)`

Comment: another bug in v42 (currently beta)  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468930

Answer (score 3):

You could have a placeholder element and replace it with the Audio element by Javascript when it's clicked...

Comment: How can I do that exactly ? :)

Comment: Okay, top of my head? <div id="placeholder"><button onclick="document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = '<audio blah blah blah>'">PLAY</button></div>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the `autobuffer` attribute to false?